# Using induction to prove linear maximum subarray algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, proof

Here's my implementation of Kadane's algorihm that I wrote OCaml:

```
let rec helper max_now max_so_far f n index = 
  if n < index then max_so_far
  else if max_now + f index < 0 
  then helper 0 max_so_far f n (index+1)
  else helper (max_now + (f index)) 
      (max max_so_far (max_now + (f index))) f n (index+1)

let max_sum f n = helper 0 0 f n 1
```

Now I want to prove formally that it is correct. My code's specification:

The function f for arguments 1 to n returns an integer. 
The function max_sum with parametres f n should return the biggest sum
of sums:

[image: sum]

Where 1<=a<=b<=n.

You don't need to analyse my code - I'm just trying to prove that Kadane's algorithm works using induction. The problem is I don't know how to approach this problem - proving simple procedures like factoring or factorials is quite straightforward but when it comes to something more abstract like finding the subarray with maximum sum I don't even know where to start. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basis of the induction won't go through, since the algorithm and the specification disagree on whether an empty subarray (having sum 0) is allowed. I'm going to follow the specification, which disallows empty subarrays.

The inductive step is as follows. For all `k`, define

```
max_now  = max_{a in 1..k  } sum_{i in a..k  } f(i)
max_now' = max_{a in 1..k+1} sum_{i in a..k+1} f(i)
max_so_far  = max_{b in 1..k  } max_{a in 1..b} sum_{i in a..b} f(i)
max_so_far' = max_{b in 1..k+1} max_{a in 1..b} sum_{i in a..b} f(i).
```

We need to show that

```
max_now' = max(max_now, 0) + f(k+1)
max_so_far' = max(max_so_far, max_now').
```

Both equalities are proved by splitting a `max`.

```
max_now' =      max_{a in 1..k+1} sum_{i in a  ..k+1} f(i)
         = max( max_{a in 1..k  } sum_{i in a  ..k+1} f(i),
                                  sum_{i in k+1..k+1} f(i))
         = max((max_{a in 1..k  } sum_{i in a  ..k  } f(i)) + f(k+1),
                                                              f(k+1))
         = max(max_now, 0) + f(k+1)

max_so_far' =     max_{b in 1..k+1} max_{a in 1..b  } sum_{i in a..b  } f(i)
            = max(max_{b in 1..k  } max_{a in 1..b  } sum_{i in a..b  } f(i),
                                    max_{a in 1..k+1} sum_{i in a..k+1} f(i))
            = max(max_so_far, max_now')
```

Comment: I can't understand your post. What does "max" mean, is it the sum of max subarray or the maximum of array? What does "max_{a in 1..k  }" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let maxSum[i] be the largest continuous array sum ending at index i. 
I'd like to prove this statement of kadane algorithm - 
`maxSum[i] = max(maxSum[i-1] + a[i], a[i])`

```
if a[i] > maxSum[i-1] + a[i]

on considering a[i+1], 
a[i] + a[i+1] > maxSum[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1]
```

So it is better to break the continuity and start new subarray from the ith index